# extract part of a string before and after a word

Tags: php, regex, string, search

i need to **extract** and show some words **before** and **after** a **query word**, something like google search results, for example:

```
$str = "hi user! welcome to new php open source world, we are trying to learn you something!";
$query = "new php";
$result = "... welcome to new php open source ...";
```

i searched google an SO but didn't find a clear answer or maybe my php knowledge was not enough!
is there a workable and easy-to-use function to do this job?

Comment: Well that's a bit vaguely specified. How much is "some words"? Always 2 on each side?

Comment: it's better to be dynamic but also static words is good, for example 10 words each side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function yourFuncName($str, $query, $numOfWordToAdd) {
    list($before, $after) = explode($query, $str);

    $before = rtrim($before);
    $after  = ltrim($after);

    $beforeArray = array_reverse(explode(" ", $before));
    $afterArray  = explode(" ", $after);

    $countBeforeArray = count($beforeArray);
    $countAfterArray  = count($afterArray);

    $beforeString = "";
    if($countBeforeArray < $numOfWordToAdd) {
        $beforeString = implode(' ', $beforeArray);
    }
    else {
        for($i = 0; $i < $numOfWordToAdd; $i++) {
            $beforeString = $beforeArray[$i] . ' ' . $beforeString; 
        }
    }

    $afterString = "";
    if($countAfterArray < $numOfWordToAdd) {
        $afterString = implode(' ', $afterArray);
    }
    else {
        for($i = 0; $i < $numOfWordToAdd; $i++) {
            $afterString = $afterString . $afterArray[$i] . ' '; 
        }
    }

    $string = $beforeString . $query . ' ' . $afterString;

    return $string;
}
```

**Output is:** `user! welcome to new php open source world,` (*$numOfWordToAdd = 3*)

Comment: Why do you use rtrim and ltrim? It´s just deleting necessary whitespaces, e.g. if you are searching for "bob" in "bob has a book" the result would like "''bob''has a book

Comment: Your function works partially, you should use preg_split if you want to work case insensitive, and you dont have to reverse the array of the before letters, otherwise it will mess the word.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an working example I thing that it is clear what I did and how:

```
<?php

$str = "hi user! welcome to new php open source world, we are trying to learn you something!";
$query = "new php";    

$expl = explode($query, $str);

    // items on the left side of middle string
    $expl_left = explode(" ", $expl[0]);

    $left_cnt = count($expl_left);

    $new_left = $expl_left[$left_cnt-3] . " " . $expl_left[$left_cnt-2];

    // items on the right side of middle string
    $expl_right = explode(" ", $expl[1]);

    $new_right = $expl_right[1] . " " . $expl_right[2];

    // new string formated
    $new = "... " . $new_left . " " . $query . " " . $new_right . " ...";

print $new;

?>
```

If you have some questions feel free to ask...

Comment: how i can make it to work dynamic? my means is return words in each side based on my word number?

Comment: it works dynamic just change $str to what ever you need and $query also and run code you will see that it is dynamic...

Comment: Dusan i said based on my word number :)

Comment: well for this code everything works fine even if you have only 1 word before and after $query. But if you want to change number of words that are shown before and after then you need to modify this script, by current status it returns 2 words before and after. 1 if only one, none if none.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(.+)?([^\s]+.{10}'.$query.'.{10}[^\s]+)(.+)?/', '... $2 ...', $str);
```

This will return the same result from the same string and query you gave.  If the before or after length starts or ends (respectively) in the middle of a word, it will continue until it completes the word before it stops.

Comment: good; but still a problem, for example for "we" this return:  ... rce world, we are trying ... is there a smarter way or can you make it smarter, please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a "word" is any series of non-whitespace characters, the following will extract 3 words on either side of `new php` out of the string `$subject`, but accept less if necessary:

```
if (preg_match('/(?:\S+\s+){1,3}new php(?:\s+\S+){1,3}/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

Change the `3`s to any number you like.

Comment: thanx, but i think your code need preg_quote to work?? i tested something like this before!

Comment: It needs that iff your needles may contain regex metacharacters, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following function with explode:

```
public static function returnSearch($query, $str, $wordcount) {
    $explode = explode($query, $str);
    $result = null;
    //if explode count is one the query was not found
    if (count($explode) == 1) {
        $result = implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($explode[0], 2), -$wordcount, $wordcount)) . " ";
    }
    //if explode count is more than one the query was found at least one time
    if (count($explode) > 1) {
        //check for if the string begins with the query
        if (!empty($explode[0])) {
            $result =  "..." . implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($explode[0], 2), -$wordcount, $wordcount)) . " ";
        }
        $result = $result . $query;
        if (!empty($explode[1])) {
            $result = $result . " " . implode(' ', array_slice(str_word_count($explode[1], 2), 0, $wordcount)) . "...";
        }
    }
    //return result
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected function from @Can Vural, it wont mess the phrase of the before match and its case insensitive, very usefull to dispaly in php search results:

```
function render_search_words($str, $query, $numOfWordToAdd) {
list($before, $after) = preg_split("/$query/i", $str);
$before = rtrim($before);
$after  = ltrim($after);

$beforeArray = explode(" ", $before);
$afterArray  = explode(" ", $after);

$countBeforeArray = count($beforeArray);
$countAfterArray  = count($afterArray);

$beforeString = "";
if($countBeforeArray < $numOfWordToAdd) {
    $beforeString = implode(' ', $beforeArray);
}
else {
    for($i = 0; $i < $numOfWordToAdd; $i++) {
        $beforeString = $beforeArray[$i] . ' ' . $beforeString;
    }
}

$afterString = "";
if($countAfterArray < $numOfWordToAdd) {
    $afterString = implode(' ', $afterArray);
}
else {
    for($i = 0; $i < $numOfWordToAdd; $i++) {
        $afterString = $afterString . $afterArray[$i] . ' ';
    }
}

$string = '...'.$beforeString . ' <span>' . $query . '</span> ' . $afterString.'...';

return $string;
```

}