# get before and after dom element php

Tags: php, laravel, explode

i want to get the words before and after an element, i can do it with a little function but im stuck if its begin or ends by this element

my element : a[id=2]
my text:

```
bla bla bla bla <a id="2">My link</a> blu blu blu
```

according to this question [extract part of a string before and after a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629081/extract-part-of-a-string-before-and-after-a-word) i created a little script that gets the link like that :

```
$left = substr($tab[0], -10);
$right = substr($right, 1, 10);
$text = "... $left $query $right ...";
```

it returns :

```
'... bla bla <a id="2">My link</a> blu blu ...'
```

but when i search in like :

```
<a id="2">My link</a> bla bla bla bla blu blu blu
or
bla bla bla bla blu blu blu <a id="2">My link</a>
```

the explode() function returns an only one array because there is nothing before/after the delimiter ... i have error "**Undefined offset: 1**"

do you have any solution to this ?

Comment: Do yuo know the parent element?  Or it not the same everytime?

Comment: `explode()` code ? and how about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12629211/861704 ?

Comment: @splash58 The parent is not the same everytime

Comment: @Jigar and with the regex i have same problem if it is in the beggining or in the end $r = preg_replace('/(.+)?([^\s]+.{0,30}'.$node->text().'.{0,30}[^\s]+)(.+)?/', '... $2 ...', $node->saveHTML()); but works fine if its in the middle...

Comment: @Samir in my answer i find `<a id=2` and take its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Suppouse, `$dom` contain `DomDocument`. Then create xpath - get text of element which is parent of tag `<a id=2...` If that `parent` wrap only one `a` tag than $text will be array with two objects - text before and text after, if contains some more elements array will have many parts, but you can combine them.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$texts = $xpath->query('//a[@id="2"]/../text()');
$text = array();
foreach($texts as $t) $text[] = $t->nodeValue;
echo implode(' ', $text);
```

Comment: yes it works fine for me! but same problem when i begin or end by the link, text[] returns only one array... a solution should ( by the way im using this library : https://github.com/wasinger/htmlpagedom thats use the Symfony domcrawler to get the parent ) a solution would be to know if the link is at the beginning or end and generate the missing part by adding a blank text? what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested i found a solution that works fine for me whether the query is in begin middle or at the end of the string.

```
function extract_before_after($str, $query)
{
    $expl = explode($query, $str);

    // if $query is at the begin
    if(isset($expl[0]) && strlen($expl[0]) === 0){
        $before = '...';
        $after = substr($expl[1], 0, 100) . '...';
        $new_text = $before . ' ' . $query . ' ' . $after;
    }
    // if $query is at the end
    elseif(isset($expl[1]) && strlen($expl[1]) === 0){
        $before = substr($expl[0], -100) . '...';
        $after = '...';
        $new_text = $before . ' ' . $query . ' ' . $after;
    }
    // if $query is in middle
    elseif(
        (isset($expl[0]) && strlen($expl[0]) > 0)
        && (isset($expl[1]) && strlen($expl[1]) > 0)
    ){
        $before = '...' . substr($expl[0], -100);
        $after = substr($expl[1], 0, 100) . '...';
        $new_text = $before . ' ' . $query . ' ' . $after;
    }
    // if $query not found...
    else{
        $new_text = '... nothing ...';
    }

    return $new_text;
}
```

thanks for your useful help